# 64-bit library limited to 4GB?

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

I'm using an image manipulation library that throws an exception when I attempt to load images > 4GB in size.  It claims to be 64bit, but wouldn't a 64bit library allow loading images larger than that?  I think they recompiled their C libraries using a 64 bit memory model/compiler but still used unsigned integers and failed upgrade to use 64 bit types.

Is that a reasonable conclusion?

**Edit** - As an after-thought can OS memory become so fragemented that allocation of large chunks is no longer possible? (It doesn't work right after a reboot either, but just wondering.)  What about under .NET?  Can the .NET managed memory become so fragmented that allocation of large chunks fails?

Comment: There is alot of 32bit enertia out there, we've been writing it since the 80's, true 64bit support will occur slowly as people rewrite parts of OSs, Libraries and Filesystems.

Comment: Just curious: what kind of images are you loading that are over 4GB?

Comment: Hooked: uncompressed high resolution bitmaps can be very large.

Comment: @Mehrdad You mean 32-bit 32K x 32K pixel images? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a reasonable suggestion, however the exact cause could be a number of things - for example what OS are you running, how much RAM / swap do you have? The application/OS may not over-commit virtual memory so you'll need 4GB (or more) of free RAM to open the image.

Out of interest does it seem to be a definite stop at the 4GB boundary - i.e. does a 3.99GB image succeed, but a 4GB one fail - you say it does which would suggest a definite use of a 32bit size in the libraries data structures.

**Update**

With regards your second question - not really. Pretty much all modern OS's use virtual memory, so each process gets it's own contiguous address space. A single contiguous region in a processes' address space doesn't need to be backed by contiguous physical RAM, it can be made up of a number of separate physical areas of RAM made to look like they are contiguous; so the OS doesn't need to have a single 4GB chunk of RAM  free to give your application a 4GB chunk.

It's possible that an application could fragment it's virtual address space such that there isn't room for a contiguous 4GB region, but considering the size of a 64-bit address space it's probably highly unlikely in your scenario.

Comment: Yes, an image just below 4GB does in fact load.  I am using WinXP 64 with 8GB of RAM.

Comment: @roygbiv: In which case I think you are on the money - while it's a '64-bit' library some data structure is limiting things to 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless perhaps the binary file format itself limits the size of images.